# Second iteration of While Loop creates an error

Tags: python

I am very new to Python, I have searched and cannot find answer. Thank you in advance.

1. I purposely type the incorrect answer and it responds properly - prompts me to give input again.
2. I now type the correct answer and it responds with error (my code is below error)

   ```
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ```

   AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    in 
   54     print("Enter Y/N:")
   55     answer = input()
   ---> 56     answer = input.upper()
   57
   58 print("Great! Lets get started.")

   AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'upper'

   ````
   `# intro text 

   print("Are you ready to create a super hero with the super hero generator 3000?")

   # Ask for input / use input() to take it / use upper() to adjust text 

   print("Enter Y/N:")

   answer = input()
   answer = answer.upper()

    # adding while loop to condition input(answer)

   while answer != "Y":
       print("Sorry, but you have to choose Y to continue.")
       print("Enter Y/N:")
       answer = input()
       answer = input.upper()

   print("Great! Lets get started.") ```
   ````

Comment: In `answer = input.upper()`, `input` is a function (that you used on the line above). Did you mean `answer = answer.upper()`?

Comment: Thank you for your help and your kindness!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
while answer != "Y":
    print("Sorry, but you have to choose Y to continue.")
    print("Enter Y/N:")
    answer = input()
    answer = answer.upper()
```

input() function has no function upper(), you want to call upper() on answer.